# Blackberry using Sqlite

Tags: sqlite, blackberry

I'm using SQ-LITE with blackberry OS 7 ,i m storing user data in the SD-card
when i try to read data from SD-card  in the simulator i should to remove and reinsert the SD-cart image . even with blackberry BOLD 9900 i have the same problem .
can some one help me please and thanks .

Comment: What does "i should" mean? Do you get an error message?

Answer (score 0):

i have many screen with list of data form SQ_LITE using select request and when i try to run one of them on simulator or in device i should remove and reinsert the SD-card to work,
i think the problem cums from creating database on SD_card when the application start,
so i tried to comment creating database and tables and it works .
maybe i must run that only one time when user open the application for the first time 
Thanks